# Magnto 2.4.4 Customer group pricing in Configurable products ignored in cart

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4.4

I've created a configurable product
I manually added existing products
All those products has a Customer Group pricing set for different quantities

All goes well until I get to the cart. Once in /checkout/cart/ the Customer group pricing are ignored.

I made some tests in a demo version of Magento 2.4.3-p1 and I don't have this problem.

Thanks in advanced,